# image queries getting called multiple times when I use FailSilently + codenameone

Tags: codenameone

This might sound vague question. But recently I started noticing queries being called repeatedly from Mobile App. This is not used to happen before. I would like to know when would this happen when there is issue with server or Mobile App code?

public Image fetchLogoImage(String app) {
        try {
            final String u = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "Logo-" + app;
            if (FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(u)) {
                int length = (int) FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getLength(u);
                setLogo(EncodedImage.create(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(u), length));
                return getLogo();

```
        }
        class ImageRequest extends ConnectionRequest {

            public EncodedImage img;

            public ImageRequest() {
                super(getLogoImageURL(app), false);
                setFailSilently(true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                try {
                    JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
                    Map<String, Object> hm = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
                    if (!hm.isEmpty()) {
                        byte[] data = Base64.decode(((String) hm.get("FileContent")).getBytes());
                        img = EncodedImage.create(data);
                        OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(u);
                        os.write(data);
                        os.close();
                    }
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                    Log.p("Wrong Application Name");
                }
            }
        }
        ImageRequest c = new ImageRequest();
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(c);
        if (c.img != null) {
            setLogo(c.img);
        }
        return c.img;
    } catch (IOException err) {
        Log.e(err);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to failing silently, it's related to silent retries which default to 1 in some platforms. You can disable silent retries via `setSilentRetryCount(0)`.